# line 1: syntax error at or near if

Tags: linux, awk

My code in treat.awk is:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
if($1 == "x") cat file
```

And my input in command prompt is:

```
~/home/treat.awk x
```

There appear an error message such:

```
line 1: syntax error at or near if
```

How to fix it? I using awk for this code and only traditional version of awk is allowed. 
File is only contains "**test**".

Comment: You don't have a real **AWK** since that would print: `awk: bailing out near line 1` ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not `awk` code, that's `csh` code. Change the she-bang to

```
#! /bin/csh -f
if($1 == "x") cat file
```

(where that `-f` is not to take a file as argument like in `awk`, but to not read the user's `~/.cshrc`)

The `awk` code to do the same thing would be something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  if (ARGV[1] == "x") exit(system("cat file"))
}
```

If by *traditional version of awk*, you mean the pre-1985 non-POSIX versions like the `/bin/awk` of Solaris, then that can't be done, as those don't have `ARGV` and can't refer to their arguments (other than with `FILENAME` when processing their arguments as input files). On Solaris, you'd want to use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` to get something close to a standard `awk`. The wording of your error message suggests you're using `mawk` though which is not  usually what one would call a *traditional version of `awk`* and does support that syntax.

Now, note that that `system()` would actually call `sh` to interpret that `cat file` shell command line¹, so you might as well do the whole thing in `sh` (which would be a lot better than `csh` which should really not be used in this century):

```
#! /bin/sh -
if [ "$1" = x ]; then
  cat file
fi
```

---

<sup>¹, also, some arguments starting with `-` would be taken as option by `awk`! With GNU `awk`, you can use a `#! /usr/bin/gawk -E` she-bang instead to work around that.</sup>

Comment: I have found the answer recently, and it is using END{ .. } between the coding. Thanks for responding!

Comment: @nerf Huh? That would make it not a valid `csh` script _nor_ a valid `awk` script...